# Making two UIViews touch-detectable when one or the other is tapped

Tags: swift, uiview, detection, touchesbegan

My issue is that I have two UIViews, and I need it to create a dot that's a certain color depending on which UIView I tap in. The problem is that when I tap, it only creates a blue dot, and even though I tap in the yellow dots view (They don't overlap) it still creates a blue dot. I don't think something is right.
My code:

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let locationTop = (touch as! UITouch).locationInView(self.topCourt)
        var dotTop = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: locationTop.x, y: locationTop.y, width: 10, height: 10))
        dotTop.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        dotTop.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.topCourt.addSubview(dotTop)

        let locationBot = (touch as! UITouch).locationInView(self.bottomCourt)
        var dotBot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: locationBot.x, y: locationBot.y, width: 10, height: 10))
        dotBot.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        dotBot.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        self.bottomCourt.addSubview(dotBot)

    }
```

I need some way to separate this so it actually detects which view I tap in and it creates the color dot it's supposed to. (I already have the creation of the dot down, the problem is detecting which view or what color to put it in)(Because no matter which view I tap in, it's always blue)

Answer (score -2):

UPDATED ANSWER:
New code:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{

        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch!
        let locationT = (touch as! UITouch).locationInView(self.topCourt)
        let locationB = (touch as! UITouch).locationInView(self.bottomCourt)

        if touch.view == topCourt{
            var dot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: locationT.x, y: locationT.y, width: 10, height: 10))
             dot.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            dot.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            self.topCourt.addSubview(dot)
        }

        if touch.view == bottomCourt{
            var dot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: locationB.x, y: locationB.y, width: 10, height: 10))
             dot.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            dot.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            self.bottomCourt.addSubview(dot)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question?  If so, please explain the solution

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.